# Enable/disable components of prefab in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As you see in the script, on destroy function I am disabling prefab's components, it goes well in the game process but after stopping the game it remains disabled, I know that the reason is that it is prefab so it saves that information but how can I disable it only when the game is being played? I've considered while loop but it crashed, also Awake function. Any ideas?

```
private void OnDestroy()
{
    Lose = true;
    ENEMIES.GetComponent<EnemiesMovement>().unit = 0.0f;
    prefenBullet.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
    prefenBullet.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Why not instantiate the prefab during run time? Then you modify or delete that instance instrad the prefab

Comment: I do instantiate, how can I cancel instantiate process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the instance in a GameObject variable so you can access and modify later in the code. Something like this:

```
// Reference to the Prefab. Drag a Prefab into this field in the Inspector.
public GameObject myPrefab;
GameObject myPrefabInstance;

    // This script will simply instantiate the Prefab when the game starts.
void Start()
{
    // Instantiate at position (0, 0, 0) and zero rotation.
    myPrefabInstance = Instantiate(myPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
}

private void OnDestroy()
{
    myPrefabInstance.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
    myPrefabInstance.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().enabled = false;
}
```